# DIfferent Behavior Between Onclick and Onload

Tags: jquery, onclick, onload

I have an index webpage that has a submit button on it.  When I click that button, I want to run a function that adds a string to a div (using onclick()).  However, it only flashes and then disappears.  But when I use window.onload, it stays on the page, as I intend.  Here's the code:

```
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="submit" onclick="test();" value="Add Text">
  </form>
  <div id="holder"></div>
</div>
```

I include the following in my page with a "script" tag.

WHen I use this, it stays on the page (as it should):

```
window.onload = function(){
  $('#holder').html("Hello <b>world</b>!");
}
```

But this disappears right after it loads:

```
function test(){
  $('#holder').html("Hello <b>world</b>!");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button you are using is a form submit button, which will submit the form and reload the page.

Instead use a `<button>` button

Use

```
<button onclick="test();">Add Text</button>
```

instead of

```
  <form>
    <input type="submit" onclick="test();" value="Add Text">
  </form>
```

Comment: Should it be `<button />` or `<input type="button" />` ? I am unsure of the current standard.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Definition and Usage

The <button> tag defines a clickable button.

Inside a <button> element you can put content, like text or images. This is the difference between this element and buttons created with the <input> element.

Tip: Always specify the type attribute for a <button> element. Different browsers use different default types for the <button> element.

Comment: @JonTaylor `button` and `input` are two different elements. `button` are not empty so `<button />` is invalid, you could use `<input type="button" />` if you want, I wouldn't and the `/>` is only needed in XHTML.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, what is the difference between button and input type button then?  I always though input type button was the more modern version of the button element?  Also I have been having to write a lot of XHTML lately hence the /> all the time :).